# Use eslint to force a specific named export?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, eslint

I'd like to use eslint to require JavaScript/TypeScript files to export a named export of a given name.

For example, in my `src/pages` directory, I'd like all files to be required to export a named export called `config`:

### Invalid example

##### `src/pages/index.js`

```
export const Page = () => {}

// Error: no export named `config`
```

### Valid example

##### `src/pages/index.js`

```
export const Page = () => {}

export const config = {}
```

Is this currently possible? I've had a look at various eslint rules, plus of course [eslint-plugin-import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-import), but haven't been able to find anything that suits this exact purpose.

Bonus points if anyone has any ideas as to how one could also enforce a specific type for this `config` export in TypeScript.

Comment: I see that there's been some time since the question was posted. Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: Haven't thought about the issue in quite some time. I think at the moment I'd suggest using a glob package to import `config` from any of the files you want/expect to export such a thing, thus any lack of an export would cause a build failure.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but here's some example code that I've verified works. I wrote essentially this exact request for requiring an exported variable of type StorybookDocumentation for essentially the same end goal.

The general gist of the approach is to write a [custom rule](https://typescript-eslint.io/developers/custom-rules/) which:

1. Starts from the Program root node, and iterates through all the tokens looking for export related tokens (in my case, I chose to go with named exports, but with slight adjustments to the logic below you can target default exports).
2. Once I've narrowed down the tokens to just exported variables and their types, I chunk them into an array of [identifier, type] tuples.
3. I then assert that at least one of those tuples is an exported variable of the correct name and type, else I report an issue.

```
import { ESLintUtils, TSESTree } from '@typescript-eslint/utils';


const arePriorTokensExportConst = (index: number, tokens: TSESTree.Token[]) => {
    const previousTokenIsConst = tokens[index - 1]?.value === 'const';
    const previousPreviousTokenIsExport = tokens[index - 2]?.value === 'export';
    const isNamedExport = previousTokenIsConst && previousPreviousTokenIsExport;
    return isNamedExport;
};
export const requireStorybookDocumentation = ESLintUtils.RuleCreator.withoutDocs({
    create(context) {
        return {
            Program(program) {
                const namedExports = context.sourceCode.tokensAndComments
                    .filter((token, currentIndex, tokens) => {
                        if (token?.type !== 'Identifier') {
                            return false;
                        }
                        const isNamedExport = arePriorTokensExportConst(currentIndex, tokens);
                        const isTypeForNamedExport =
                            tokens[currentIndex - 1]?.value === ':' &&
                            arePriorTokensExportConst(currentIndex - 2, tokens);
                        return isNamedExport || isTypeForNamedExport;
                    })
                    .reduce<TSESTree.Token[][]>((acc, cur, index) => {
                        if (index % 2 === 0) {
                            acc.push([cur]);
                            return acc;
                        }
                        acc[acc.length - 1].push(cur);
                        return acc;
                    }, []);

                if (
                    !namedExports.some(namedExport => {
                        const [identifier, identifierType] = namedExport;
                        return (
                            identifierType?.value === 'StorybookDocumentation' && identifier?.value === 'Documentation'
                        );
                    })
                ) {
                    context.report({
                        messageId: 'require-storybook-documentation',
                        node: program,
                    });
                }
            },
        };
    },
    meta: {
        docs: {
            description: 'Function Component files should export a Storybook documentation configuration',
        },
        messages: {
            'require-storybook-documentation': 'Define and export a StorybookDocumentation object named Documentation',
        },
        type: 'suggestion',
        schema: [],
    },
    defaultOptions: [],
});

export default {
    'require-storybook-documentation': requireStorybookDocumentation,
} satisfies Record<string, ESLintUtils.RuleModule<any, any>>;
```

And then some tests to verify it behaves as expected

```
import { RuleTester } from '@typescript-eslint/rule-tester';
import { describe, after, it } from 'mocha';
import { requireStorybookDocumentation } from '../rules';
RuleTester.afterAll = after;
RuleTester.describe = describe;
RuleTester.it = it;
RuleTester.itOnly = it.only;

const ruleTester = new RuleTester({
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    parserOptions: {
        project: './tsconfig.json',
        ecmaFeatures: { jsx: true },
        tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
    },
});

ruleTester.run('my-rule', requireStorybookDocumentation, {
    valid: [
        {
            code: `
    import { FunctionComponent } from 'react';
    import { StoryObj, Meta } from '@storybook/react';

    type StorybookDocumentation<TComponent extends FunctionComponent, TDefinedStories> = {
        Meta: Meta<TComponent>,
        Stories: Record<TDefinedStories, StoryObj<TComponent>>
    };

    export const MyComponent: FunctionComponent = () => <h1>Hello World!</h1>;
    export const Documentation: StorybookDocumentation<typeof MyComponent, 'Primary'>  = {
        Meta: {
            component: MyComponent,
        },
        Stories: {
            Primary: {}
        }
    };
`,
        },
    ],
    invalid: [
        {
            code: `
        import { FunctionComponent } from 'react';
        export const MyComponent: FunctionComponent = () => <h1>Hello World!</h1>;
    `,
            errors: [{ messageId: 'require-storybook-documentation' }],
        },
    ],
});
```